# Cannot change style in Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a paragraph like this:

> Nov 19, 2014 - You are running the search on the Selection, but you're
>   not changing that selection between runs. So you just end up making
>   the same text bold over and over again. Here's a way to do what you're
>   doing without the Selection object: Sub ParaStyle() Dim objPara As
>   Paragraph For Each objPara In ... Word VBA Paragraph
>   formatting-VBForums

And I am trying to change the style of the entire paragraph to a local style. I am using the following code:

```
Dim rgePages As Range
Dim p As Paragraph

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=3
Set rgePages = Selection.Range
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=6
rgePages.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End
rgePages.Select

For Each p In rgePages.Paragraphs
If p.Style <> "Heading 1" Then

p.Style = "Body Text"
'p.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleBodyText
rgePages.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd

End If
Next
```

It is working fine till the time any line or a few words are in different style. Say for example if the line

> So you just end up making

in the paragraph is in different style, it is marking the whole paragraph as "Body Text" except for that part. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to clear formatting first before you apply your own style. It could go this way:

```
....
If p.Style <> "Heading 1" Then

    p.Range.Select 
    Selection.ClearFormatting 'it rather works with selection only

p.Style = "Body Text"
....
```

Comment: That was so helpful! I have been trying this for hours now trying to search the net. Thank you so much.